# Select a href in WordPress Primary Navigation to open modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am creating WordPress theme and trying to open modal by clicking on `li` element containing `a href` inside navigation menu

My code is working in static html:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal1 = document.getElementById("myModal-registration");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn1 = document.getElementById("sign-up");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn1.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "block";
};

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span1.onclick = function() {
    modal1.style.display = "none";
};


// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal1) {
        modal1.style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    z-index: 1000;
}


/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 60%;
    @media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
        width: 100%; 
    }
    .container {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        display: block;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 20px;
      //  margin: 0 auto;
    }
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
 <nav class="navBar">
        <nav class="wrapper">            
            <ul>       
                <li class="pure-menu-link"><a href="#sign-in" id="sign-up">SIGN UP</a></li> 
            </ul>  
        </nav>
    </nav>
    
    
 

    <div id="myModal-registration" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <form class="modal-content-animate" action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="container">
      <!--<label><b>Email</b></label>-->
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
        <br>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
        <br>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>
         <br>
      <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal-registration').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

But in WordPress a menu is registered in `functions.php` :

```
function register_theme_menus() {

    register_nav_menus(array( 
        'primary-navigation' => __( 'Primary Navigation' ),
    ));
}
```

and is called using PHP in `header.php`:

```
   wp_nav_menu(array(
                'container' => 'ul',
                'menu_class' => '',
                'theme_location' => 'primary-navigation',
                'menu' => 'primary-navigation'
           ));
```

after all, generated HTML code have no id for `a href`:

```
<ul id="menu-main-navigation" class="">
<li id="menu-item-20" class="pure-menu-link menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-20"><a href="#sign-up">SIGN UP</a></li>
</ul>
```

A custom URL with `#` was set in WordPress Menu options:
[image]

and was attempted to be selected as `a href` by using JS:

```
var btn1 = document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='#sign-up']");
```

but without any decent results. Am I missing a point here and using only JS is not an valid option in this case?
Let me know if you have any additional questions. 
Many thanks for all possible help, will be looking forward.

Comment: Why not add a custom menu link and put an anchor there instead of a link. You will the see the anchor displayed as the href for the custom menu link.

Comment: I have updated my question @Ihazkode , you will see that custom menu link is added as `a href`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu-item (li) in wp menus usually have a unique class. In your case its  `menu-item-20`
You can target the link you are asking with  `.menu-item-20 a`
so use

```
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn1= document.querySelector(".menu-item-20>a")
```

Comment: A wild error in console appeared : `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByClassName is not a function`

Comment: fixed answer try new script